# How does Apache handle a "script src=" that points to a Django url?

Tags: javascript, python, django, apache2, django-urls

Using the Django development webserver, my app runs perfectly.

But using Apache2, it chokes on a script tag, returning '404 Not Found'.

Script tags that point to static files work fine in both Apache and Django's development server:

```
<script src="{% static 'ideatree/client/scripts/misc.js' %}"></script>  {# WORKS!! #}
```

But the tag:

```
<script src='initFirebaseCLIENT/'></script>
```

That is routed by:

*urls.py*

```
re_path(r'^map/initFirebaseCLIENT/$', views.initFirebaseCLIENT),
```

to:

*views.py*

```
def initFirebaseCLIENT(request):                                                                     
    print("HERE", file=sys.stderr)  # NEVER GETS HERE
    filename = 'ideatree/firebaseCredentials/client/initFirebaseCLIENT_DEVELOPMENT.js'
    fp = open(filename,'r')
    content = fp.read()
    fp.close()
    return HttpResponse(content, content_type="text/javascript")
  except Exception as err:
    return HttpResponse(str(err), status=406)
```

..throws an exception at the call of the def() and the print statement never executes.  Here's the traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /ideatree/map/initFirebaseCLIENT/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/mysite/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/h [wsgi:error]  response = get_response(request)
File "/var/www/mysite/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/h [wsgi:error]  response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/var/www/mysite/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/h [wsgi:error]  response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kw[Sat Dec 28 01:41:16.596978 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 24940:tid 140471540647680] [remote ::1:54569]   File "/var/www/mysite/wsgi/../debugTools/wsgiPdb.py", line 17, in __[Sat Dec 28 01:41:16.596992 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 24940:tid 140471540647680] [remote ::1:54569]     return self.__object(*args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/mysite/wsgi/../ideatree/views.py", line 140, in initF [wsgi:error]  print("HERE", file=sys.stderr)
File "/var/www/mysite/wsgi/../ideatree/views.py", line 140, in initF [wsgi:error]  print("HERE", file=sys.stderr)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/bdb.py", line 51, in trace_dispatch
return self.dispatch_line(frame)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/bdb.py", line 70, in dispatch_line
if self.quitting: raise BdbQuit
[wsgi:error] bdb.BdbQuit
```

To be safe, I a) opened up the file permissions with a chmod 777 to both the directory and file that I'm trying to fetch, and b) added the following to the Apache2 virtualHost config:

```
<Directory /var/www/mysite/ideatree/firebaseCredentials>
  <IfVersion < 2.4>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
  </IfVersion>
  <IfVersion >= 2.4>
      Require all granted
  </IfVersion>
  <Files initFirebaseCLIENT_DEVELOPMENT.js>
    Require all granted
  </Files>
</Directory>
```

**What am I not understanding about how Apache handles a src attribute that points to Django's url handler rather than to Apache's static file handler?**

Comment: Remove the `try` / `except` to see the actual exception.

Comment: @KlausD  I've edited the question, taking out the try: block in the view and amending the Traceback to show what resulted from doing that.

Comment: Interesting.  Here's one solution that works.` <script>{% include "initFirebaseCLIENT_DEVELOPMENT.js.ln" %} </script> `

Comment: Though a) maybe the previous comment's solution is insecure external javascript? (the included file is a soft link) and b) I'd still like to understand why a basic src= attribute that uses Django's url routing doesn't work.